# Unable to enable IK on someone else's rig

Tags: animation, maya, rigging

I'm using someone else's character rig for reference but I'm not sure how I can enable IK solvers for the arms.  The hand controller has a NURBS control with an ikBlend attribute, but when I try to use the "Enable IK Solvers" tool, I get an error saying the attribute is locked or connected.

Clicking "Unlock Selected" on the attribute doesn't fix it.  Breaking the connections also breaks the ability for it to drive the enabled/disabled state of the IK handle.

The rigged character can be downloaded here if anyone wants to try to help me out: http://www.antcgi.com/2014/06/03/free-model-15-kila-lods-rig-dynamics/

[image]

Comment: I'm not very familiar with maya, but have you tried duplicating the character? In some programs when you import a 3d object it is locked (because its imported and not "meant" to be edited). However when you duplicate it, it treats it like a native object and has no idea it was imported.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to download the file to try it out for you (it says page not sound). But you could try, instead of using the button, look in the channel box, where it says IK Blend type in 1 and see if it changes, or click in the nurb control that looks like a hand and look in that channel box for the same thing and try it there. Otherwise could your try posting your file then I could have a look.